# iOS: Store new photos using UIImagePickerController NOT in default album

Tags: ios, uiimage, iphoto

I am using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to store a new photo on the iPhone (code see below).

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

This works fine. However I would like to store new photos in a different album. Not the default one.

**EDIT**

I am using the following block to create the album.

```
ALAssetsLibraryGroupResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *assetGroup)
    {
        [assetGroup addAsset:myasset]
    };

ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"in failureblock, got an error: %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};
[library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:name resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];`
```

**I am using the UIImagePickerController. How do I get the asset of a new image? When/where do I call UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum to store it?**

Comment: Have you gotten an answer or figured out how to use addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName to add new albums to the photo library? If so, would you be so kind as to post your code as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since iOS 5** you can create a new album with `addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:resultBlock:failureBlock:` using the [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Okay, sounds awesome! I am new to iOS. Could you please provide me a example of how to use this in a block with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.